# Manga about a man who learns magic in order to rescue his sister

Tags: story-identification, manga

Since MangaRock went down a while ago, I used to have an old account on my old phone and am now just remembering where I read it right this moment.

The MC is told his sister is being sold to I think a count/noble to his area and he goes and injures himself. This then triggers an old man to speak to him and help him (kind of like a soul guide) saying that he has a way he can save his sister. So he learns the old man's magic and teleports to the capital and goes to a guild and applies as a magician/sorcerer. A side character says to not lie, so he teleports behind the guy and shows he is one.

Then he takes on the task of saving the princess of that kingdom, turns out she had an aquatic parasite in her uterus that she may have contracted from her trips outside the castle. He was going to reveal who did it, and the princess's brother in law was getting nervous.

Another thing that happened was that the castle's royal mage tried going against him, but got scared by the old man, and when asked where he learned his magic, he told a fake story that it was passed down from generation to generation in secret and his magic was not the original magic creator's magic. Also he fought a royal guard and won. He also saves his sister and we learn they like each other.

Comment: If this is the one I remember. Prologue start with the old man(a great sage) lost to a young kid. Then the old man reincarnated but dont remember anything. MC with black hair. His sister black hair too. The old man is that man past life. The rest is like what you said. Please confirm if this it true.

Answer (score 3):

The manga you are looking for is *Almadianos Eiyuuden*

> In a world called as Dormant, a man who is the closest to god, Bernst is in anguish. From his youth he climb to the strongest, united and ruled that world, but now all that left of him is vanity. Spending all his days in neverending victories and glory didn’t quench his thirst for the excitement and emotion he felt a long time ago. The great sorcerer decided to create avatar of himself on another world and let it have his own consciousness, and thus, Kratss grow without any knowledge of his origin and secret. Bernst didn’t realize, the place the boy raised in , is a countryside village with no contact to Sorcery and this boy talent lies in his herculean physical prowess. Several years later, the legend of a duo in one body, between the elegant sorcerer and meathead warrior started!

**So he learns the old man's magic and teleports to the capital and goes to a guild and applies as a magician/sorcerer. A side character says to not lie, so he teleports behind the guy and shows he is one.**

[image: Almadianos Eiyuuden - Learning teleportation]
[image: Almadianos Eiyuuden - Sorcerer confrontation]
[image: Almadianos Eiyuuden - Demonstration]

**Then he takes on the task of saving the princess of that kingdom, turns out she had an aquatic parasite in her uterus that she may have contracted from her trips outside the castle.**

[image: Almadianos Eiyuuden - Womb Parasite]
[image: Almadianos Eiyuuden - Aquatic parasite]

Comment: Omg  thanks so much for finding it, I was stuck on the whole thing for a night and decided to post and see if anyone knew, who knew it would be answered thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: @Jennifer You're welcome. If the answer is satisfying, could you please mark it as accepted? Thank you.